# $(...).thirdPartyPlugins is not a function - Typescript

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, jquery-plugins

I've just followed this [guide](https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc), in order to install [bootstrap-material-datetimepicker](https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker) on my Angular 5 project, but simply importing jQuery and bootstrap-material-datetimepicker like this:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap-material-datetimepicker';
```

the plugins was crushing because it didn't found jQuery and moment so I added them in mine .angular-cli.js

Now the error is: `ERROR TypeError: $(...).bootstrapMaterialDatePicker is not a function` on calling `$('#date').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker ();`

I also tried to add an interface in typings.d.ts:

```
interface JQuery {
   bootstapMaterialDatePicker() : JQuery;
}
```

and

```
constructor() {
           $(document).ready(() => {
             console.log($.isFunction($.fn.bootstrapMaterialDatePicker));
      });
```

(also without $(dcument).ready and in ngOnInit instead constructor) returns me *false*, but if I run `$.isFunction($.fn.bootstrapMaterialDatePicker)` in chrome console it reurns *true*

Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you're using the angular/cli, this should be as simple as the following:

In your .angular-cli file, add the references to JQuery and bootstrap-material-datetimepicker:

```
"scripts": [
    ...
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js"
    ...
]
```

Make sure you do jquery ***first!*** If you are using different versions of these repos than I am, you may have to update the paths to match your own set-up.

After that, go to the component you want to use it in and add the following:

```
declare var $: any;
```

And then use it as normal:

```
$('#date').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker();
```

Note that with the cli you don't need to do the manual imports:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap-material-datetimepicker';
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that imports are unnecessary.
I've just added the bootstrap-material-datetimepicker in .angular-cli
`"scripts": [
       "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
       "../node_modules/moment/moment.js",
       "../node_modules/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js"
       ],`
but the error remains the same.